# Selenium Web-driver automation not working properly

Tags: python, selenium

So I found this script online, which is meant to brute-force web-forms online etc. using Selenium, and I thought it would be a good idea to take it, modify it a bit and experiment with it. This time, I tried creating a bot that:

1. Signs up to Twitter
2. Goes to twitter.com
3. Posts something.
4. Logs out.
5. Loop 1, 2, 3, 4 again

However, when I run the script, it just pops up a browser window and does nothing. Then the Terminal ends the Python script like it did its work correctly and finished with no problems...

Code (note that the script might look weird for what I want, but that's because I found the script as a web-form brute-forcer online, and decided to modify it to my needs):

```
#!/bin/python
from mainLib import *
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import simplejson as json
import sys
import optparse

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36")
driver = "reserved"

def userExists(username):
    try:
        driver.get("https://twitter.com/"+username)
        assert (("??" or "?Twitter / ?") not in driver.title)
    except AssertionError:
        print '\033[1;31mUser\033[1;m',
        print '\033[1;35m@%s\033[1;m' %username,
        print '\033[1;31mdoes not exist.\033[1;m',
        print '\033[1;33mTrying with the next Username...\033[1;m'
        print ' '
        return 1
    except:
        'uknown error'

def login(user, password, delay):
    try:
        print '\033[1;33mCreating account with mail: \033[1;m' + '\033[1;35m' + password + '\033[1;m' '\033[1;33m ...\033[1;m'
        sleep(2)
        if driver.current_url == 'https://twitter.com':
            print '\033[1;33mPlease retry using a different IP Address (Proxy/VPN).\033[1;m'
            driver.get("https://twitter.com/signup")
        if driver.title == "Login on Twitter":
            driver.get("https://twitter.com/signup")
            sleep(3)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_id('full-name')
        elem.clear()
        elem.send_keys('john')
        elem = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
        elem.clear()
        elem.send_keys(password)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
        elem.clear()
        elem.send_keys("twitter1")
        sleep(3)
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        sleep(delay + 3)
        if driver.title == "Twitter / Error":
            print '     \033[1;31mFailed!\033[1;m'
            driver.get("https://twitter.com/signup")
            sleep(3)
        if driver.title == "Login to Twitter":
            print '     \033[1;31mFailed!\033[1;m'
            driver.get("https://twitter.com/signup")
            sleep(3)
    #   if "This email is already registered." in driver.page_source:
    #       print '     \033[1;31mFailed!\033[1;m'
        if driver.current_url == 'https://twitter.com/account/access':
            print '     \033[1;31mFailed!\033[1;m'
            print ("")
            print '\033[1;33mPlease retry using a different IP Address (Proxy/VPN).\033[1;m'
            driver.close()
            sys.exit("")

        assert (("Enter your phone") not in driver.title)

    except AssertionError:
        print '     \033[1;32mSuccess!\033[1;m'
#       print '\033[1;35mEmail: \033[1;m' + password
#       print '\033[1;35mPassword: \033[1;m' + "twitter1"
#       print("")
        try:
            f = open('CreatedAccounts.txt','a')
        except:
            f = open('CreatedAccounts.txt','w')
        f.write(password+'\n')
        f.close()
        driver.get("https://twitter.com")
        elem = driver.find_element_by_id('tweet-box-home-timeline')
        elem.clear()
        elem.send_keys('It worked!')
        elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="timeline"]/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/button')
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.get("https://twitter.com/logout")
        sleep(5)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.js-submit").click()
        sleep(5)
        driver.get("https://twitter.com/signup")
    #   driver.delete_all_cookies()
    #   return 1
#   else:
#       print '\033[1;33mPlease check your Internet Connection.\033[1;m'

def dictionaryAttack(usernames,passwords,delay):
    if str(type(usernames)) == "<type 'list'>":
        for username in usernames:
            #if (userExists(username) == 1):
            #   continue
            driver.get("https://twitter.com/signup")
            sleep(delay)
            print("Creating Accounts...")
            print("")
            for password in passwords:
                if (login(username,password,delay) == 1):
                    cj.clear()
                    break
def main():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option('-f', '--file', action="store", dest="userfile", help="File containing valid usernames (one per line)", default=False)
    parser.add_option('-d', '--dictionary', action="store", dest="dictionary", help="Text file containing passwords", default=False)
    parser.add_option('-u', '--username', action="store", dest="username", help="A valid username", default=False)
    parser.add_option('-t', '--time', action="store", dest="delay", help="Delay (in seconds) - use this option based on your Network Connection speed.", default=True)
    options, args = parser.parse_args()

    global driver

    if (options.delay is None):
        delay = 4
    else:
        delay = int(options.delay)
    print '\033[1;33mUsing\033[1;m',
    print '\033[1;35m%d second(s)\033[1;m' %delay,
    print '\033[1;33mof delay between login attempts.\033[1;m'
    print ' '

    if ( (options.userfile == False) and (options.username == False) ) :
        print 'You have to set an username or a userfile'
        exit()
    if ( (options.userfile != False) and (options.username != False) ) :
        print 'You can\'t set both options at once.. choose between username or userfile'
        exit()
    if (options.dictionary == False):
        print 'You have to set a valid path for the passwords dictionary.'
        exit()

    try:
        f = open(options.dictionary,'r')
        passwords = []

        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            passwords.append(line.strip('\n'))
        f.close()
    except:
        print 'Check the path to the dictionary and try again.'
        exit()

    if (options.userfile != False):
        try:
            f = open(options.userfile,'r')
            usernames = []

            while True:
                line = f.readline()
                if not line:
                    break
                usernames.append(line.strip('\n'))
            f.close()
        except:
            print 'Check the path to the users file and try again.'
            exit()

            driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
            driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        dictionaryAttack(usernames,passwords,delay)
    else:
            driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
            driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        dictionaryAttack(options.username,passwords,delay)

    driver.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: your browser does nothing, it does not even navigate to twitter url?

Comment: @YuZhang Nope, it just opens the browser window, and does nothing at all. Doesn't even navigate to a URL or anything...

Answer (score 0):

See the link below. That could be the problem.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2257